# How do I loop through HTML DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

I want to loop through a nested HTML DOM node, as shown below:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="nested-div-one">
    <div class="nested-div-two">
      <div class="nested-div-three">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-div-one">
    <div class="nested-div-two">
      <div class="nested-div-three">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this using Javascript to loop through every single one of the dividers?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector("div")` to get a list of all the DIVs, then loop over that.

Comment: @Barmar although a good solution, OP wasn't specific about the divs

Comment: It might be useful to understand what the end goal is here. Are you just trying to loop through each of these nodes? Or do you need to interact with the furthest down child nodes? Depending on the use case, it could change the optimum output.

Comment: You can loop over `Node.childNodes`, testing for `Node.nodeType === 1`, if you must have them in nested order. If you want them all then loop over `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`.

Comment: @fingeron He said "all the dividers", I thought he meant divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing OP was not specific for DIV elements, here's a more dynamic approach:

So first you wanna get the first container, in your case it's:

```
var mainEl = document.getElementById('main');
```

Once you have that, each DOM element has a `.children` property with all child nodes. Since DOM is a tree object, you can also add a flag to achieve **recursive behavior**.

```
function visitChildren(el, visitor, recursive) {
   for(var i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
       visitor(children[i]);
       if(recursive)
           visitChildren(children[i], visitor, recursive);
   }
}
```

And now, let's say you want to change all div backgrounds to red:

```
visitChildren(mainEl, function(el) { el.style.background = 'red' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla javascript for this

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(el => {
  // el = div element
  console.log(el);
});
```